# How to get “Company” and “Office” from Active Directory given a UserPrincipal object?

Tags: active-directory, userprincipal

How to get “Company” and “Office” from Active Directory given a `UserPrincipal` object?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read an attribute that the `UserPrincipal` class does not expose, then you need to use the [`GetUnderlyingObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getunderlyingobject) to use the underlying `DirectoryEntry` object (which is what `UserPrincipal` uses in the background. This is one reason I don't bother using `UserPrincipal` at all anymore.

The AD attributes you are looking for are [`company`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-company) and [`physicalDeliveryOfficeName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-physicaldeliveryofficename). Assuming you have a `UserPrincipal` object called `user`, you would do it like this:

```cs
var underlyingObject = (DirectoryEntry) user.GetUnderlyingObject();

var company = underlyingObject.Properties.Contains("company") ?
    (string) underlyingObject.Properties["company"].Value :
    null;

var office = underlyingObject.Properties.Contains("physicalDeliveryOfficeName") ?
    (string) underlyingObject.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value :
    null;
```

You use `Contains` to verify the attribute is in the collection. If the attribute is empty, it won't appear in the `Properties` collection at all.